# Power analysis for binomial regression (success/failure)

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, sample-size, statistical-power

I've collect 161 people for a study which the original power analysis was based on correlations, but now I've realised binomial regression would be better. I can find a lot of articles on comparing binomial proportions (45/60 vs 48/60) and linear regressions, but nothing about a regression predicting a proportion (specifically one with success/fail: 48/60 rather than proportion success: 80% )

I have a variable (ordinal, 0-30) predicting performance in each block of 60 trials. My research question is: does Unex predict performance?

```
`res <- glm(cbind(B1_success, (60 - B1_success)) ~  Unex, data = Df, family = "binomial")`
```

I'm not sure what the effect size would be to use for this either, as glm does not give overall effect sizes except for beta coefficients(?). Overall, I wanted to work out power for 77%, 78%, 82%, 83% etc. (H1) compared to 80% (H0), or small, medium, strong effect size? And post-hoc achieved power.

Any help would be appreciated! Sorry if this is unclear, my first post.

I've seen [Power analysis for binomial data when the null hypothesis is that $p = 0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38439/power-analysis-for-binomial-data-when-the-null-hypothesis-is-that-p-0) but not sure its relevant to me.

**Edit**: Thanks for the help. I've added an R function that other might find useful

```
powerBinom<-function(beta, N, outcomeVariance, predictorSD){

    if (outcomeVariance >.25) {print("ERROR: Maximum 0.25 for binomial outcome")}

    powerBinom = 1 - pnorm(1.96 - beta * predictorSD * sqrt((N*outcomeVariance)))
      print(powerBinom)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, post hoc power [is a load of crap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/384013/111259), so let's just get that out of the way.

If you want to know power for detecting an effect, you need to know a few things first.

- The marginal variance of the outcome.
- A minimal detectable effect per one unit standard deviation increase in the predictor.  The reason I say one standard deviation increase in the predictor is because it gives us one less thing to estimate in the power calculations.

The power achieved by having these things and a sample size of 161 at a 0.05 significance level is
$$ \gamma = 1 - {\bf{\Phi}}(1.96-\vert\beta\vert\sigma_x \sqrt{(np(1-p)} )$$

Here $\bf{\Phi}$ is the CDF for a standard normal distribution.  $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation for your predictor.  If it is 1, as I suggest, then $\beta$ is the change in log odds per one standrd deviation change in the predictor.  Also, $p(1-p)$ is the marginal variance of the outcome, regardless Unex.

Does that help answer your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out! I've not heard of marginal variance before. I've calculated: the proportion response of each level of the DV (e.g. 0.2 level 1, 0.3 level 2 etc). Then i've calculated the variance the usual way (value - mean, ^2, summed, divided by n-1):  6.685216e-05 for me. 

I've tried to translate the equation to R code as that's how my brain works (beta as 1, my predictor SD is 6.2)

power = 1 - dnorm(1.96 - 1 * 6.2 * sqrt(161 * 6.685216e-05) ) )
           = 0.83
Not sure if I followed you correctly, as if i increase my beta to 2 the power is reduced to 0.68?

Comment: @ChristopherDawes Marginal varince is just the variance of the outcome without taking into account covariates.  If I were to ask "What is the variance of weight for people who are 6 foot tall" that would be conditional variance (because I am asking about people who are 6 foot tall).  If I were to ask "what is the variance of weight for *people*" that would be marginal variance, because I don't care about height.

Comment: Got it - i'm just not sure how to apply this? For example now in R i've tried 
beta = 1, sd = 6.2, marginal variance= 274

1 - dnorm(1.96 - beta * sd * sqrt(161*marginalVariance) )

Which comes out as 1, as the CDF returns 0 with those values, unless i'm using the wrong function? Sorry if this is really obviously, i've tried to calculate power outside of gPower!

Comment: Marginal variance can't be larger than 0.25 for a binomial outcome.  Also, dnorm is the density of the normal, not the cdf.  You want to use pnorm.

Comment: Got it! I'd converted my outcome to % (0-100) which is why it wasn't working. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me, 0.001% of the PhD done. I'll copy my code into the question for others. Will also read the power articles you cited.

Thanks again!

Comment: Does this approach work when the predictor is an indicator variable? In my case, I'd like to establish whether two binomial regressions differ. I thought I could encode them as one, with the indicator variable distinguishing one from the other.  What would be $\sigma_x$ in that case? The sd of the discrete uniform distribution with 2 levels? What if I have more than two regressions?

Comment: @IgorF.  I think its best if you ask your own question separately.  If you link me to it, I will answer it

Comment: @DemetriPananos Sure, here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/568299/169343